# what mean details java version "1.8.0_211"?

Tags: java

How to identify java version from this?
Does 8u mean java 8 or another version.
Please tell me what is "1.8.0_211" hidden meaning.

Comment: 1.8 is java 8 and 211 is the patch version.

Comment: Note [since Java 10 they've changed the version-string format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/version-string-format.htm#JSJIG-GUID-DCA60310-6565-4BB6-8D24-6FF07C1C4B4E).

Comment: Also: **JavaScript != Java**

Answer (score 1):

**8u121** means **java 8 update 121** and will shown as  `java version "1.8.0_121"` and in a folder like `jdk1.8.0_121`.